# Cannot extract .tbwx file in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Cannot extract .tbwx file for Google Data Analytics Cert. One of the issues is, when trying to open the file I'm prompted to choose from free trial, key, or sign-in since this is enterprise level software. If I try free trial, I get an error saying my free trial is over and the others are not an option.

Fortunately, I do have access to Tableau, but I cannot gain access to the file. I've tried a few suggestions that did not help. I would appreciate any advice on how I can extract the file outside of Tableau and then upload the files.

Thanks Danielle

I tried opening the file in the Tableau which I still have access to but it will not extract. I am getting this error: Can't Upload Files This file type is currently not supported on the web. To use this type of file, connect to it from Tableau Desktop and then publish it to the server. Dashboards Starter Template.twbx.